# Matrices and unique and infinite solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If a matrix has a row of zeros but the number of variables is equal to the number of nonzero rows, does that mean the matrix has an infinite amount of solutions or a unique solution?

Comment: Why not write down a simple example, and work it out? By the way, matrices don't have solutions – systems of equations have solutions.

Comment: And matrices don't have variables! Tell me, what are the variables in $\pmatrix{1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4}$?

Comment: Sorry I should have meant the variables in the system of equations.

Answer (score 0):

No, not necessarily. It all depends on the rest of the rows.

The only thing a zero row adds is that it requires the product on the same row to become zero. A zero row may turn an otherwise solvable equation into insolvable (that is turn the existence of one or more solution into zero).

Otherwise if the equation is of the form where the result on that row is zero the solutions are the same as if that row was removed.

And as you may know a matrix with as many rows as variables may have an unique solution or infinite numbers of solutions (or even no solution at all).

Example1:

$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}x = \begin{pmatrix}42 \\ \alpha \\ \beta\end{pmatrix}$$

of course has no solution because the first row must become zero.

Example2:

$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}x = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ \alpha \\ \beta\end{pmatrix}$$

has the same solutions as

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}x = \begin{pmatrix}\alpha \\ \beta\end{pmatrix}$$

Example3:

$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\
1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}x = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ \alpha \\ \beta\end{pmatrix}$$

has the same solutions as

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}x = \begin{pmatrix}\alpha \\ \beta\end{pmatrix}$$

which is zero if $\alpha\ne\beta$ and $x=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha \\ t\end{pmatrix}$ (for any $t$) if $\alpha = \beta$.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that we are taking about:

$$A x = b$$

If the non zero rows in $A$ are independent and equal to the number variables, and corresponding elements to the zero rows in $b$ are zero, then you will have a unique solution.